# If else return issue in the loop in python

Tags: python, if-statement, return

Function should count how much expression as y is in request and if there is no y in request function should return "there is no y in request". I need to reduse else return expression, but in this case progran doestn't work properly.
I need to make expression as:

```
def foo():    
    number = 0
    for x in request:
       if x == y:
           number += 1

        return "there is no y in request"

    return number
```

but even if x is y it gives "x is not y". If I use else like:

```
def foo():
    number = 0
    for x in request:
       if x == y:
          number += 1

       else:
           return "there is no y in request"

    return number
```

But else return is against syntax rools. How to correct code?

Comment: It's unclear what your code is supposed to do and what's not working correctly. Please see the [mcve] article.

Comment: Also please post the actual message indicating the syntax error

Comment: are you sure you need to check if x *is* (the same object as) y ? maybe it's `if x == y` ?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I correct the question

Comment: As @Aran-Fey mentioned: add a minimal working example. What is `y`? Where is it defined? Very difficult to answer the question in its current form.

Comment: "else return" is allowed by the language, not "against syntax rules", and probably what you want.  But as others have suggest, a MCVE would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few problems with this code:

- It is clear that `number` is supposed to count the total occurrences of `y` in `request`. A `return` statement immediately terminates a function returning a value. When you want to iterate and process every element of `request` you need to continue the execution. That code does not work because it stops at the first element which is not `y` and returns, instead to continue.
- y is not defined
- Semantically, a function is reusable because of the arguments you may pass in order to vary its calls depending on your needs

The following works:

```
y = 5

def foo(request):
    number = 0
    for x in request:
       if x is y:
          number += 1
    return "there is no y in request" if number == 0 else number

foo([1,2,5])
```